Broken vertical cursor movement in custom text editor
I am trying to implement vertical cursor movement (up and down arrow keys) in my custom nano-like text editor, but I could not get it working properly and keep introducing new bugs. My text editor uses a gap-buffer to store the text and a single variable pos_idx to handle the insert position. It is the job of the render function to convert that linear cursor position to x and y coordinates. The left and right arrow keys work just fine, as they only need to increment or decrement pos_idx.
main.zig
const std = @import("std");
const ncurses = @cImport({
    @cInclude("ncurses.h");
});
const buffer = @import("gap_buffer.zig");
const editor = @import("editor.zig");

pub fn main() !void {
    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    defer {
        _ = gpa.detectLeaks();
        _ = gpa.deinit();
    }

    const alloc = gpa.allocator();

    _ = ncurses.initscr();
    defer _ = ncurses.endwin();
    _ = ncurses.keypad(ncurses.stdscr, true);
    _ = ncurses.noecho();
    _ = ncurses.raw();
    _ = ncurses.refresh();

    var e = try editor.Editor.init(alloc);
    defer e.deinit();

    var char: c_int = 0;

    while (char != 'q' & 0x1f) {
        char = ncurses.getch();
        try e.handle_key(char);
        try e.render();
    }
}

editor.zig
const std = @import("std");
const gap_buffer = @import("gap_buffer.zig");
const ncurses = @cImport({
    @cInclude("ncurses.h");
});

pub const Editor = struct {
    buf: gap_buffer.GapBuffer,
    alloc: std.mem.Allocator,
    render_buf: []u8,
    pos_idx: usize = 0,
    render_buf_dirty: bool = false,

    pub fn init(allocator: std.mem.Allocator) std.mem.Allocator.Error!Editor {
        return Editor{ .buf = try gap_buffer.GapBuffer.init(8, allocator), .alloc = allocator, .render_buf = try allocator.alloc(u8, 9) };
    }

    pub fn deinit(self: *Editor) void {
        self.buf.deinit();
        self.alloc.free(self.render_buf);
    }

    pub fn handle_key(self: *Editor, key: c_int) std.mem.Allocator.Error!void {
        if (key == ncurses.KEY_LEFT) {
            if (self.pos_idx > 0)
                self.pos_idx -= 1;
        } else if (key == ncurses.KEY_RIGHT) {
            if (self.pos_idx < self.buf.buf.len - self.buf.gap_len)
                self.pos_idx += 1;
        } else if (key == ncurses.KEY_UP) {
            try self.handle_up();
        } else if (key == ncurses.KEY_DOWN) {
            try self.handle_down();
        } else if (key <= 255) {
            self.render_buf_dirty = true;
            try self.insert(@intCast(key));
        }
    }

    pub fn render(self: *Editor) std.mem.Allocator.Error!void {
        const t = self.buf;

        if (t.gap_len == t.buf.len) return; // nothing to render

        try self.refresh_render_buffer();

        var y: u64 = 0;
        var line_begin_idx: ?usize = null;
        var line_len: usize = 0;

        for (self.render_buf[0..self.pos_idx], 0..) |c, i| {
            if (c == '\n') {
                y += 1;
                line_begin_idx = i;
            } else {
                line_len += 1;
            }
        }
        var x: usize = undefined;

        if (line_begin_idx == null) {
            x = self.pos_idx;
        } else if (self.pos_idx == line_begin_idx.?) {
            x = line_len;
        } else {
            x = self.pos_idx - line_begin_idx.? - 1;
        }

        _ = ncurses.clear();
        _ = ncurses.mvprintw(0, 0, @ptrCast(self.render_buf));
        _ = ncurses.move(@intCast(y), @intCast(x));
        _ = ncurses.refresh();
    }

    fn insert(self: *Editor, char: u8) std.mem.Allocator.Error!void {
        self.buf.set_pos_idx(self.pos_idx);
        try self.buf.insert(char);
        self.pos_idx += 1;
    }

    fn handle_up(self: *Editor) std.mem.Allocator.Error!void {
        try self.refresh_render_buffer();
        var curr_line_idx: usize = std.mem.lastIndexOf(u8, self.render_buf[0..self.pos_idx], "\n") orelse return; //
        var x: usize = undefined;

        // this is an edge-case, where we are on a newline
        if (self.render_buf[self.pos_idx] == '\n') {
            x = 0;
            curr_line_idx = self.pos_idx;
        } else {
            x = self.pos_idx - curr_line_idx - 1;
        }

        const prev_line_idx: ?usize = std.mem.lastIndexOf(u8, self.render_buf[0..curr_line_idx], "\n");

        if (prev_line_idx) |prev_idx| {
            self.pos_idx = prev_idx + @min(x, curr_line_idx - prev_idx - 1);
            return;
        }

        self.pos_idx = @min(x, curr_line_idx);
    }

    fn handle_down(self: *Editor) std.mem.Allocator.Error!void {
        try self.refresh_render_buffer();
    }

    fn expand_render_buffer(self: *Editor) std.mem.Allocator.Error!void {
        const t = self.buf;
        const l = t.buf.len - t.gap_len;
        if (self.render_buf.len >= l + 1)
            return;

        self.alloc.free(self.render_buf);
        self.render_buf = try self.alloc.alloc(u8, l * 2 + 1);
    }

    fn refresh_render_buffer(self: *Editor) std.mem.Allocator.Error!void {
        if (!self.render_buf_dirty)
            return;

        const t = self.buf;
        try self.expand_render_buffer();

        @memcpy(self.render_buf[0..t.gap_begin_idx], t.buf[0..t.gap_begin_idx]);
        @memcpy(self.render_buf[t.gap_begin_idx .. t.buf.len - t.gap_len], t.buf[t.gap_begin_idx + t.gap_len ..]);
        self.render_buf[t.buf.len - t.gap_len] = 0; // null terminator for c-printing

        self.render_buf_dirty = false;
    }
};

gap_buffer.zig
const std = @import("std");

pub const GapBuffer = struct {
    gap_begin_idx: usize,
    gap_len: usize,
    pos_idx: usize,
    buf: []u8,
    alloc: std.mem.Allocator,

    pub fn init(gap_size: usize, allocator: std.mem.Allocator) std.mem.Allocator.Error!GapBuffer {
        const buffer = try allocator.alloc(u8, gap_size);
        return GapBuffer{ .gap_begin_idx = 0, .gap_len = gap_size, .buf = buffer, .pos_idx = 0, .alloc = allocator };
    }

    pub fn deinit(self: *GapBuffer) void {
        self.alloc.free(self.buf);
    }

    pub fn insert(self: *GapBuffer, char: u8) std.mem.Allocator.Error!void {
        if (self.gap_len == 0)
            try self.expand_gap();

        self.move_gap_to_cursor();
        self.buf[self.pos_idx] = char;
        self.gap_begin_idx += 1;
        self.gap_len -= 1;
    }

    pub fn set_pos_idx(self: *GapBuffer, idx: usize) void {
        if (idx <= self.gap_begin_idx) {
            self.pos_idx = idx;
        } else {
            self.pos_idx = idx + self.gap_len;
        }
    }

    fn expand_gap(self: *GapBuffer) std.mem.Allocator.Error!void {
        std.debug.assert(self.gap_len == 0);

        const text_size = self.buf.len - self.gap_len;

        const new_gap_len = (self.gap_len + 1) * 2;

        var new_buf = try self.alloc.alloc(u8, text_size + new_gap_len);
        @memcpy(new_buf[0..self.pos_idx], self.buf[0..self.pos_idx]);
        @memcpy(new_buf[self.pos_idx + new_gap_len ..], self.buf[self.pos_idx..]);

        self.alloc.free(self.buf);
        self.gap_begin_idx = self.pos_idx;
        self.gap_len = new_gap_len;
        self.buf = new_buf;
    }

    fn move_gap_to_cursor(self: *GapBuffer) void {
        if (self.gap_begin_idx == self.pos_idx) {
            return;
        }

        if (self.pos_idx > self.gap_begin_idx) {
            const gap_end_idx = self.gap_begin_idx + self.gap_len;
            const diff = self.pos_idx - gap_end_idx;
            std.mem.copyForwards(u8, self.buf[self.gap_begin_idx .. self.gap_begin_idx + diff], self.buf[gap_end_idx .. gap_end_idx + diff]);
            self.gap_begin_idx = self.gap_begin_idx + diff;
            self.pos_idx = self.gap_begin_idx;
        } else {
            const diff = self.gap_begin_idx - self.pos_idx;
            const save_pos = self.pos_idx + self.gap_len;
            std.mem.copyBackwards(u8, self.buf[save_pos .. save_pos + diff], self.buf[self.pos_idx .. self.pos_idx + diff]);
            self.gap_begin_idx = self.pos_idx;
        }
    }
};

The functions where I need help are handle_up and handle_down in editor.zig. The implementation in handle_up doesn't work i.e. the cursor seems to jump to wrong x-positions and sometimes skip empty lines.
Any help on the implementation would be appreciated.
I tried using lldb to find out what was wrong, but I kept introducing new bugs and edge-cases.

Why is this tagged C if you're using Zig?
